# Python проверка имён пользователей

Tags: python, if

Должно быть так: если имя в списке `new_users` уже использовалось раньше (есть в списке `current_users`), то тогда можно выводить сообщение, что нельзя это имя использовать.
В другом случае если не было ранее имя использовано, то тогда должно выводиться, что имя доступно.

```py
current_users = ['Vlad', 'Michael', 'Andry', 'Alex', 'Admin']
new_users = ['Stas', 'Anna', 'Andry', 'Alex', 'Max']
for current_user in current_users:
    for new_user in new_users:
        if current_user.lower() == new_user.lower():
            print(f'имя {new_user} использовалось, выберите другое имя')
else:
    print(f'имя {current_user} доступно для регистрации ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать конструкцию `if in`

```
old = ['a', 'b', 'c']
new = ['new', 'a', 'b']


for name in new:
   if name in old:
        print(f'имя {name} использовалось, выберите другое имя')
   else:
        print(f'имя {name} доступно для регистрации ')


# имя new доступно для регистрации 
# имя a использовалось, выберите другое имя
# имя b использовалось, выберите другое имя
```

## Что за in?

in, в зависимости от того, чем является объект после него, проверяет следующее:

- Если это строка - происходит проверка на "содержание подстроки" или "вхождение"

  `print("He" in "Hello")  # True`
- Если это структура по типу список/кортеж и т.д. - происходит проверка на содержание этого элемента

  `print(1 in [1, 3, 5]) # True`
  `print(2 in [1, 3, 5]) # False`

P.S. В словарях проверяется содержание по ключам

```
print('bar' in {'bar': 13, 'foo': 7}) # True
print('car' in {'bar': 13, 'foo': 7}) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте множества, здесь циклы не нужны:

```
current_users = {'Vlad', 'Michael', 'Andry', 'Alex', 'Admin'}
new_users = {'Stas', 'Anna', 'Andry', 'Alex', 'Max'}

print(f'Имена {new_users.intersection(current_users)} использовались, выберите другое имя')
print(f'Имена {new_users.difference(current_users)} доступны для регистрации ')
```

```
Имена {'Andry', 'Alex'} использовались, выберите другое имя
Имена {'Stas', 'Anna', 'Max'} доступны для регистрации
```

Примечание. Это регистрозависимый вариант. Если нужен регистронезависимое сравнение, можно предварительно перевести все значения в множествах, например, в нижний регистр.